# How do I differentiate between getchanges REST API call for SPSite and SPWeb?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spweb, spsite

I'm trying to query SPSite for changes but I can't seem to figure out the difference between that and querying SPWeb.

I'm following this documentation

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn499819.aspx#bk_WebGetChanges

Am I querying SPSite or SPWeb, I am confused.

If my site collection is

> https://abccompany.sharepoint.com/teams/f1

and I am using the following endpoint

> https://abccompany.sharepoint.com/teams/f1/_api/web/getchanges

am I querying SPSite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query particular object with REST API, you need to use appropriate object in url.

For example consider following REST queries:

- Get changes for site collection:

```
https://sp.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_api/site/getchanges(@qry)?@qry=%7b%22Update%22%3atrue%7d
```

- Get changes for web:

```
https://sp.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_api/web/getchanges(@qry)?@qry=%7b%22Update%22%3atrue%7d
```

- Get changes for a list:

```
https://sp.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_api/Lists/getbytitle('MyList')/getchanges(@qry)?@qry=%7b%22Update%22%3atrue%7d
```

In your case query `https://sp.sharepoint.com/teams/f1/_api/web/getchanges` will get changes for SPWeb object.